# To recognize a text from a file contains a string and not contains others

Tags: c#, regex

I have to check text files content to see if it contains certain words (ex: hello, hi) but not contains somes (ex: bye, again):

```
dfadsfdsf hello sir,
good morning, how are you
```

Regex.IsMatch will return true
but

```
hello sir,
good morning, how are you
hssss bye some 
some other
```

Regex.IsMatch will return false

Please help me with RegEx string.

Words can appear in any order and may not stand alone: bye can be byebye or byeabc.

I am using VS2019.

Comment: I believe your problem is multiline, for which you need to add `\s` flag to the regex.

Comment: Take out each row. Check for a match with a regular expression: (?=.*\b(hi|hello)\b)(?!.*\(bye|again)\b).*

Answer (score 1):

Two lookaheads should do it for you - one positive and one negative:

```
(?=.*\b(hi|hello)\b)(?!.*\b(bye|again)\b).*
```

`(?=` starts a positive lookahead looking for the words *hi* or *hello*. The `\b`, a word boundary anchor, makes sure it's not a part of a word that's found, like t**hi**ck.

Then `(?!` is the negative lookahead, making sure the words *bye* and *again* aren't present.

When that's made certain, `.*` matches anything until the end.

And, as pointed out in a comment, You need to set the `RegexOptions.Singleline` option.

**Edit:** Obviously I hadn't read the question thoroughly enough :/. If you want matches on words where only a part is matched, remove the word boundary anchors `\b`.

Comment: I have test **(?=.*(hi|hello))(?!.*(bye|again)).*** with the second text, it still return true, please check.

Comment: if bye appear before hello, the result is still true. In that case I need false!

Comment: ^(?=.*(hi|hello))^(?!.*(bye|again)).* works, Tks